# How to get input with HTML tags in flutter app

Tags: android, html, flutter, text, native

I am developing a mobile app using flutter. It should have a text field like this. [image]

From this input field I want to get input as a normal text with given controls and want to store it in the form of HTML. For example consider below text.

**Hi this is my title**
*This is sample text*

I want to store it my database in the form of HTML like bellow.

```
<b>Hi this is my title</b><br>
<i>This is sample text</i>
```

How can I do this using flutter?

Answer (score 1):

For simple html tags like above you can use the **styled_text** package.

```
StyledText(
  text: text.replaceAll("<br>", "\n"),
  tags: {
    'b': StyledTextTag(style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    'i': StyledTextTag(style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic))
  },
);
```

link: https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text

Comment: Thanks. It is a use full package for me. But I don't know where the user will use bold, italic kind of things. Is it possible to combine those all together as single variable at the end?. I mean can I take an output like below?

`<b> Hi </b> how are you. <i> I am busy with work</i> <br> We will meet tomorrow.`

Can i get whole this as on input variable at the end? I don't know where the user use these tags.